# Multiple Authentication Providers in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have configured two authentication providers in my Spring Security config:

```
   <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider ref="XProvider" />
      <security:authentication-provider ref="YProvider" />
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

Does spring security evaluate both providers? Or does it stop to evaluate if one of them fails? If not, How to make it stop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can specify as many providers as you want. They will be checked in the same order you declared them inside the authentication-manager tag.

Once a successful authentication is made, it will stop polling the providers. If any provider throws an `AccountStatusException` it will also break the polling.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It should be mentioned, that this is not a core feature of Spring-Security but of the default AuthenticationManager implementation which supports a list of AuthenticationProvider instances.

Comment: How to tell it move to next provider if Exception is not type of AccountStatusException  ?