# How can I fallback to BASIC or FORM authentication when SPNEGO can't be used for a client?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, spnego

I finally configured my JBoss AS 7 server to use `SPNEGO` on an AD domain against Windows 2008 R2. I'm using Java 7.

When a user accesses the server URL from somewhere other than a domain computer (say, from a mobile phone or the wider Internet), they're prompted for a username and password then I get the error:

```
Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unsupported negotiation mechanism 'NTLM'
```

When the user access the url when logged in on the domain it's all ok.

On the `SPNEGO` security-domain (`standalone.xml`) I configured 2 login-modules:

First: `org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule`

Second:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    <module-option name="usersProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/spnego-users.properties"/>
    <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/spnego-roles.properties"/>
    <module-option name="defaultUsersProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/spnego-users.properties"/>
    <module-option name="defaultRolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/spnego-roles.properties"/>
</login-module>
```

The question is: How can I fallback to `BASIC` or `FORM` when `SPNEGO` is out of scope?

Thanks

Full exception follows:

```
00:40:23,751 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-9090-8) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unsupported negotiation mechanism 'NTLM'.
        at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.spnegoLogin(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:230) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
        at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.innerLogin(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:194) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
        at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:137) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.authenticate(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:187) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would suggest you using the Spring Security with SPNEGO extension.
Please see something like: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/

After that, you can have MORE authentication providers.

Citation taken from:
[Multiple Authentication Providers in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502/multiple-authentication-providers-in-spring-security)

*You can specify as many providers as you want. They will be checked in same order you declared them inside the authentication-manager tag.
Once a successfull authentication is made, it will stop polling the providers. If any provider throws an AccountStatusException it will also break the polling.*

This way, you will not be dependent on specific application server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify WEB-INF/web.xml file to fallback to basic:

```
<context-param>
  <description>BASIC Authentication FallBack</description>
  <param-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.BasicAuthFallBack</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See here for details:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SECURITY-793