# Handle spring bean failures in java application

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I'm totally new to spring framework.I'm working on an application that involves two types of authentication for the incoming request.In bean.xml i have 2 types of handler for these authentication.My requirement is ,if one authentication handler fails ,it should not break and simply it should proceed on to next authentication handler.How can i achieve this.??Can we specify in bean.xml,if a handler throws an exception,the spring execution should not fail and it should continue with the next authentication.

Comment: Can you paste your bean.xml file

Comment: @abcd:Is there a way to handle this in Bean.xml??I'm unable to post the xml file.sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unable to post your `bean.xml` file , I am assuming you have declared your authentication managers like:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider ref="AAuthProvider" />
  <security:authentication-provider ref="BAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

By default, spring is designed to evaluate the handlers in a linear fashion. Meaning, they will be evaluated in order. If one fails, it automatically goes to the next one.

References:

- [AuthenticationManager, ProviderManager and AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-authentication-manager)
- [Multiple Authentication Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502/multiple-authentication-providers-in-spring-security)