# How to execute custom handler before Spring authentication manager

Tags: spring, spring-security

I wanted to know whether it is possible to have custom handler execution just before spring authentication manager. I wanted to validate licenses for the user before he access system. Initially i wrote custom filter and executed it before calling to authentication manager, but in this case he wont be able to access some resources since he is not authenticated, but later i moved my code to sucessHandler of spring which worked fine, except it has some security issues like if open in multiple tabs it fails.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brijesh

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to add a Spring [AuthenticationProvider.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) In short, an AuthenticationManager has a list of AuthenticationProviders, each of which is queried in order. The question and answer to [Multiple Authentication Providers in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502) has a good explanation of this. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html) also explains how the various components fit together.