# Provider order using AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 4.0.1 and want to use multiple authentication providers for authentication using Java-based configuration. How do I specify the provider order?

I was hoping to use [AuthenticationManagerBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html), since that's what `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configureGlobal()` exposes, but I don't see any way to specify the order. Do I need to create a [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) manually?

**Update:** Here's a problem clarification based on Arun's answer. The specific providers I want to use are `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and `DaoAuthenticationProvider` for a custom `UserService`.

Ultimately I'd like to authenticate against the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` first and the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` second.

The AD provider involves a call to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider()` but the DAO provider involves calling `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.userService()`, which creates a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` around the user service behind the scenes. Looking at the source code, it doesn't directly place a provider in the provider list (it creates a configurer), so Arun's answer isn't working for me here.

I tried creating the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` manually and passing it to `authenticationProvider()`. It didn't impact the order.

Comment: Can I please see your spring security configuration code ? I would like to see how the authentication providers have been configured

Answer (score 4):

I tried an objectPostProcessor inside the configure method and it worked. Not sure if this is what you want:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
           .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
      auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(this.dataSource));

      auth.objectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<Object>() {
        @Override
        public <O> O postProcess(O object) {
            ProviderManager providerManager = (ProviderManager) object;
            Collections.swap(providerManager.getProviders(), 0, 1);
            return object;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the *configure* method that goes on your *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* inherited class.

The reason for the object post processor is that we need to wait the AuthenticationManagerBuilder to actually build the object before we can access and change the order of the providers list.

Hope it helps.. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah, it works and you can apply it, when you use ```authenticationManagerBuilder
          .ldapAuthentication()``` (when ldap is on the last place and you can not force it to be before custom authentication providers)

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit ordering provision. The order of invocation will be the order in which you have provided your `AuthenticationProvider`to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider()`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502/multiple-authentication-providers-in-spring-security) for xml configuration. The same should apply for java config as well.

For eg

```
auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider2());
auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider1());
```

will result in the following order of invocation `AuthenticationProvider2,AuthenticationProvider1`

and

```
 auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider1());
 auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider2());
```

will result in the following order of invocation `AuthenticationProvider1,AuthenticationProvider2`

Comment: Thanks Arun. I looked at the code and can see that this works for AuthenticationProviders we explicitly pass through the authenticationProvider() method, so +1 for that. But I'm trying to get this to work with the UserService. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem in my Spring 5 application, but in my case creating `DaoAuthenticationProvider` helped. Here's my code (I omitted a lot of it and pasted the most important one).

```
...
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(userDetailsAuthenticationProvider());

            if (isSsoEnabled()) {
                authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
            }

            if (isKerberosEnabled()) {
                authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider userDetailsAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
            = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }

    private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(getAdDomain(), getAdServer());
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper((UserDetailsContextMapper) userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }


    private boolean isSsoEnabled() {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(ConfigurationFileUtils.getConfigurationProperty("security.use-sso"));
    }

    private boolean isKerberosEnabled() {
        return isSsoEnabled() && Boolean.parseBoolean(ConfigurationFileUtils.getConfigurationProperty("security.use-kerberos"));
    }    
}
```