# Angular with Spring Security Login and Authentication

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are using AngularJS in frontend and spring in backend. Spring security shall do the authentication and login, but it doesnt even work with the help of spring's tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/). Everytime we are trying to log in the "user"-service the principal object is null. In frontend we are receiving this answer: `data = Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}` EVERYTIME. Doesn't matter logging in with correct or incorrect data...I read so many articles, but I couldn't find a solution.

Our **login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="LoginApp">
    <div class="modal show" ng-controller="LoginController">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" ng-change="checkValid()" ng-disabled="requesting">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="input-block-level" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" ng-change="checkValid()" ng-disabled="requesting">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="error" ng-bind="errormessage" ng-show="error"></span>
                <!--
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                -->
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--
            <button class="btn btn-link">Forgot password?</button>
            -->
            <button class="btn btnExtra btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="submitLogin()" ng-disabled="requesting || !valid">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Our **login.js**:

```
(function(angular) {
                const app = angular.module("LoginApp",[]);
                app.controller("LoginController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
                        $scope.username = "";
                        $scope.password = "";
                        $scope.errormessage = "";
                        $scope.error = false;
                        $scope.valid = false;
                        $scope.requesting = false;
                        $scope.submitLogin = function() {
                           $scope.requesting = true;
                           $scope.error = false;
                           const credentials = {
                               username: $scope.username,
                               password: $scope.password
                           };
                           const headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
                                + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
                                 } : {};
                           $http.get("user", { headers: headers }).then(function(data){
                               if(data.data.name) {
                                   window.location.href = "/";
                               }
                               else {
                                   $scope.error = true;
                                   $scope.requesting = false;
                                   $scope.errormessage = "Username / Passwort ist falsch!";
                               }
                           },
                           function(reason) {
                               $scope.error = true;
                               $scope.requesting = false;
                               if(reason.status === 404 || reason.status === 408){
                                   $scope.errormessage = "Verbindung zum Server konnte nicht hergestellt werden!";
                               }else if (reason.status === 403){
                                   $scope.errormessage = "Username / Passwort ist falsch!";
                               }else{
                                   $scope.errormessage = "Unbekannter Fehler ist bei der Anfrage aufgetreten! Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut";
                               }
                           })
                        };
                        $scope.checkValid = function(){
                            if($scope.username != undefined && $scope.username != null && $scope.username.length > 1 &&
                            $scope.password != undefined && $scope.password != null && $scope.password.length > 1){
                                $scope.valid = true;
                            }else{
                                $scope.valid = false;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ]);
            })(window.angular);
```

Our **authentication-service (as mentioned in tutorial or many posts):**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

The SecurityWebAppInitializer with a custom filter that shall log the IP and username.

```
@Order(2)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super.beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
        insertFilters(servletContext,new MultipartFilter(),new MDCFilter());
    }
}
```

Finally our **Spring Security config**

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
             .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select email,pwHash,true from user where email = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select email, rolle_rollenname from user where email = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user", "/login", "/logout", "login.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //.logoutSuccessHandler(new customLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
            .antMatchers("/stylesheets/**");
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
    { 
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository; 
    }
}
```

When using custom authentication and the default loginpage it works without problems. **Maybe the login.html or login.js is wrong**...

**UPDATE**

When I use .httpBasic() without specifying the loginform a browser dialog appears when I try to access a secured ressource.
I want a redirect to the custom login page instead of the browser dialog. **How to do?**

Comment: I think you should go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/multiple-authentication-provider-spring-security-java-config/35369153#35369153) for spring auth security

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly do you think is wrong in my code?

By the way, when I do a simple Form with method="post" and action="login" it works with this authentication.

But no in the way with angular and this service.

Comment: Actually your code is too long so I am not getting exactly where you had a mistake, ok I post some auth code in angular may be it will help you

Comment: `$http.get("user", { headers: headers }).then(function(data){
                               if(data.data.name) {...`

Right at this call is the mistake.

Comment: $http Method is right but I think you forgot to write `/` before user : `$http.get("/user", { headers: headers }).then(...` because url start with `/`

Comment: Nope, when I am using the debug mode of my tomcat the service will be invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it by using JSON Web Tokens, a custom Stateless Filter and giving the token everytime back to the frontend, when they ask for sth.

Comment: Simple question I want to ask, you achieved this with the angular app at frontend and spring-boot app at backend? Didnt you require to integrate springsecurity form login in the frontend app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.factory('AuthFactory', ['$http', 'contextPath', '$q', '$timeout', function ($http, contextPath, $q, $timeout) {

            function User() {
            };

            var currentUser = null;

            var userChangeCallbacks = [];

            var notifyUserChange = function (newUser) {
                angular.forEach(userChangeCallbacks, function (callback) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        callback(newUser);
                    });
                });
            };

            var exported = {
                getCurrentUser: function () {
                    return currentUser;
                },
                refresh: function () {
                    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                        //Get the current user
                        $http.get(contextPath + '/rest/user/current')
                                .success(function (data) {
                                    currentUser = new User();
                                    for (var key in data) {
                                        currentUser[key] = data[key];
                                    }
                                    notifyUserChange(currentUser);
                                    resolve(currentUser);
                                })
                    });
                },
                registerUserChangeHandler: function (callback) {
                    console.log("registered handler: " + callback);
                    userChangeCallbacks.push(callback);
                }
            };

            return exported;
        }]);
```

Then call that refresh method in your login controller.

**LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.login = function (username, password) {
            UserService.login({
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            }, function () {
                AuthFactory.refresh();
                $state.go("home");
            });
        };
```

Comment: What exactly does this script and where specific shall i call the "refresh" method?
When I'm using the default loginpage my authenticatoin is correct. So it is probably a problen in my login.html or in my javascript.

**How does the header look like from angular/javascript?**

Comment: but I think your js code is right and there is some problem in spring security, it permit all your antMatchers()

Comment: what kind of problems?