# Combine form based and oauth2 based login providers in a spring boot 2 + spring security 5 app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I currently have a working setup for a form based login in my app using spring boot 2.0.6 and spring security 5:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

There are also examples of adding support for oauth2 with the following spring dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and a helpful blog post that does well to show how you can use it:
https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

How do I extend my current security config to add support for Oauth2 logins such as facebook?

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: You can possibly add multiple authentication providers and refer to the blog in getting authentication from an OAuth provider like facebook. I am thinking out loud as this may need some more prototyping

Comment: Thanks Tuhin. I know combined with the quoted dependency and in place of the Config class I can get the flows for facebook working quite easily with this:
 
`
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2Login();
 `
but just not sure how to combine the two

Comment: Does this example help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers