# Spring Boot - Authentication via local DB or Active Directory depending on flag

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, active-directory

I developed a Spring Boot application a while ago and use a local database for the user authentication.

Now, since the application is used more and more, I also want to enable authentication via my company's active directory.

I still want to keep all the users in my local user table to reference them from other tables but check username and password against the active directory for some users. Whether the user is and active directory user or local user is kept in the user table.

In pseudo code it would look something like this:

```
if(user.isAdUser()) {
    checkCredentialsAgainstAD();
} else {
    checkCredentialsAgainstLocalDb();
}
```

My current authentication code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /* http.authorizeRequests()... */
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(new CustomUserDetailsService(userDao)).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

and loads the user information from the database via the `userDao` in the overridden `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userDao.readUserByLogin(username, true);

    if(user == null){
        log.info(username + " not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found");
    }

    User userObj = user.clone();
    userObj.password = null;

    return new CustomUserDetails(user.loginName, user.password, getAuthorities(user), userObj);
}
```

I already figured out that I could add an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` like this

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("DOMAIN", "ldap://example.com")).userDetailsService(new CustomUserDetailsService(userDao)).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
})
```

But that would always use the active directory.

**How can I specifically choose which authentication provider will be used?**

I don't want to test all providers in order like suggested in [Java Spring Security config - multiple authentication providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers) but only the right one, depending on a flag which I get from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Spring Security config - multiple authentication providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers)

Comment: "Each Authentication provider is tested in order." is not what I want to do.

Comment: I think you will have to define your custom AuthenticationProvider and to use an instance of ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider as a delegate.

Comment: And how do you know that your user isAdUser? Where does the user comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your requirement , I think perhaps the most simplest solution is to create your custom `AuthenticationProvider` which internally wraps both `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

Only this custom `AuthenticationProvider` will be registered .During the authentication , you first get the user from DB to determine their "authentication mode" and delegate to `DaoAuthenticationProvider` or `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` accordingly for further authentication.

Something like below ,feel free to modify :

```
@Service
public class MyCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

        @Autowired
        private DaoAuthenticationProvider dbAuthProvider;

        @Autowired
        private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adAuthProvider;

        @Autowired
        UserDAO userDao;

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{

            // Determine username
            String username = (authentication.getPrincipal() == null) ? "NONE_PROVIDED": authentication.getName();
            User user = userDao.getUserByName(username);
            if(user == null){
                throw new  AuthenticationException("Sorry. No this user.");
            }

            if(user.isAdUser()) {
                return adAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
            } else {
               return dbAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication){
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
        }


}
```

But how to wire them by annotated configuration is another story needed to be follow up.....