# How to configure multiple authentication provide in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, ldap

In my spring boot project, I would like to provide 2 authentication provider.
1. Authenticate user from database
2. Authenticate user from LDAP.

How do I configure multiple authentication provider in spring boot.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Spring Security config - multiple authentication providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
```

public CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
      @Override
      Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
           //TODO write your authentication logic
        }
```

}

public class CustomSessionBasedWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    
authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
```

//Here we can add as many providers as we have.
}
}