# How to do pluggable authentication in Spring Boot JavaConfig?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, plugins

I am <strike>migrating</strike> modernizing a monolithic web application into Spring Boot micro-projects.

One of the greatest features of the old application, all based on XML config, was the authentication plugin model. By turning on and off designated Spring profile, I could enable certain ways of login.

Mainly I have:

- Log in as "root" with password encrypted in config (and yes, default password is notoriously "root")
- Username and password compared with hashes stored in the database
- Active Directory
- Generic LDAP
- Preauth Headers SSO (i.e. SiteMinder and compatible)
- OAuth2 via Office 365
- X509
- SAML 2.0
- Multiple customer-specific plugins, each of which has their own profile

Each plugin had its own XML configuration file protected by respective profile.

Now I have done the following:

```
@Order(90) //Lowest, so it is the first
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http//

            .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                //<sec:xss-protection/>
                .xssProtection(xXssConfig -> xXssConfig.block(true))
             .... and so on

            .formLogin(formLogin -> .....)
    }


    //Generic configuration of the AuthenticationManagerBuilder
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.eraseCredentials(true);
        super.configure(auth);
    }

}

@Order(101)
@Profile(SpringProfiles.ROOT_USER)
@Configuration
public class RootUserSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        log.warn("Initializing authentication for security profile {}", getBeanName());
        auth.authenticationProvider(rootAuthenticationProvider());
    }

}

@Order(102)
@Profile(SpringProfiles.DATABASEUSER)
@Configuration
public class DbUserSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        log.warn("Initializing authentication for security profile {}", getBeanName());
        auth.authenticationProvider(dbAuthenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

**Motivation**: I want to develop (**move**) some plugins, especially those which bring a lot of JARs (like SAML) to different Gradle projects to include only at build according to the installation requirements. This is why I am **not** putting everything under the same `@Configuration` class. Spring auto scan will do the rest by identifying available configuration classes.

My problem is that now when I try to log in using username and password I get the following error

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
```

It is my understanding that the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is not bound to any provider, where it should be bound to a `ProviderManager` providing two providers, one for root and one for the database user.

Please note that while I am developing piece-by-piece, I chose to have *ported* only system account and database login, and leave additional plugins for the next coding days.

**Question**: why is using additional `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` classes not correctly registering the newly added `AuthenticationProvider`s to the context?

---

Edits

What I also tried:

- Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers) I tried to change my plug ins to `@Autowired` methods injecting the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` but had no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to extend from `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` rather than `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

This because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is a "global" configuration that generates a security filter. Inside, it generates a configurer object for the `AuthenticationManager`, which is `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

In order to let this instance **flow** across profiles beans, Spring looks for additional beans implementing `SecurityConfigurer<AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationManagerBuilder>`, of which `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` is a convenient abstract class.

This approach is to be used only for authentication providers hooked to username/password authentication.

SSO plugins, which require an additional filter, should be declared differently. I will work on them next days.