# SAML integration with spring boot with DB login(Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am integrating SAML2 with my existing application that already uses the login using the database with CustomAuthenticationProvider. When I am adding SAML login then the application's database login doesn't work. In my opinion, `.antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()` doesn't work. If I remove SAML configuration then the DB login works fine.
Here is the configurations: [MultiHttpSecurityConfig](https://gist.github.com/jyotiverma0310/87aefe049241a704de15133b872e242a), [CustomAuthenticationProvider](https://gist.github.com/jyotiverma0310/1948c5371defc373e98d5e8d463307bc)

In the above configuration, only SAML login works not DB login.

Comment: are you adding both auth providers something like: `auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider()).authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);`?

Comment: @Ritesh No, I am adding them in their respective configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solved it by using the following configuration. I created separate WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for application login and SAML login.

    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
    @Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

Key is to add @Autowired for configure() and add @Order(). I am not sure why it worked but below config worked for.

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class SamlAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider).authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
         }

    }
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405109/5907830) helped me to resolve this.