# Springboot multiple login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to enable multiple login instead of single person login.
I've developed single person login by following however, don't know how to do multiple login. Anyone please help?

Account.java file:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {

    private Long id;
    private String studentId;
    private String password;

}
```

This is my controller. 
`@GetMapping("/create")` was made to check whether the password is properly hashed or not.

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public Account create(){
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setStudentId("123");
        account.setPassword("123");

        return accountService.save(account);
    }
}
```

This is my service layer

```
@Service
public class AccountService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByStudentId(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(account.getStudentId(), account.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    public Account save(Account account) {
        account.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(account.getPassword()));
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }
}
```

This is my repository setting

```
@Repository
public class AccountRepository {

    private Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Account save(Account account) {
        account.setId(random.nextLong());
        accounts.put(account.getStudentId(), account);
        return account;
    }

    public Account findByStudentId(String username) {
        return accounts.get(username);
    }
}
```

How can I enable multiple users login?

Comment: you can multiple `AuthenticationProvider` for multiple user logins here is the link 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers

Answer (score 0):

Few tips after seeing your code:

1. Make a simple login JS page and try to get data on form submit URL(use path variable to read it.)

`@RequestMapping(path = "/{create}/{user}")
    public String createUser(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("pass") String pass) {
        // read id & pass then save
    }`

2.Always decode your password and match .i.e both id & password should be matched.

by this you can create as many user you want.