# How to serve 2 different API with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, api

i have a spring boot application that provides an API consumed by a frontend app (CRUD operation). This spring boot app is based on oauth2.0 authentication standard to verify the JWT access token received in the header of each API against an authorization server. I want to provide another API to be consumed by a backend (M2M usage). This API will rely on same database (same entities) but it will be slightly different (only Read operations are allowed here and responses contain more fields). Also this new API will rely on an  another authorization server to verify the JWT token.

Firstly, i was thinking to provide both API with the same spring boot application, but it looks like it will a hack to support both (for instance issuer uri of the token are diferent, port can be different, path of API are different..).

So, I'm now thinking to separate the 2 APIS into 2 different spring boot application, so that the apps are isolated by nature, but i'm not sure it's a good practice at the end? For instance, what about the concurrency issues that can occur with such design ? In the opposite, can i build easily teh 2 spring boot apps that share the same code repo (some code should be common for both apps). Those are the questions i have, so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with multiple authentication providers. Example given in following -
[Java Spring Security config - multiple authentication providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers)