# JWT authentication with fallback to SAML2 for the same path

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I'm using `spring-security-saml2-service-provider` for authentication in one of my spring boot applications and I'm using a custom `JwtAuthorizationFilter` (via a http Authentication header) in a different spring boot application.

They both work perfectly on their own.

Now I need to write a spring boot application that uses both of them. If the JWT token is available (Authentication header), then use the `JwtAuthorizationFilter`, otherwise use `saml2Login`.

The **SAML2** configuration looks like this: (There is **no filter**, just the `saml2Login`)

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/saml2/service-provider-metadata/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()

            // use SAML2
            .saml2Login()
            .addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider>() {
                public <O extends OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider> O postProcess(O samlAuthProvider) {
                    samlAuthProvider.setAuthoritiesExtractor(authoritiesExtractor());
                    samlAuthProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(authoritiesMapper());
                    return samlAuthProvider;
                }
            })
        ;
    }
```

The **JWT** configuration looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()

            // use JWT
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil))
        ;
    }
```

I think I need something like a `JwtOrSaml2AuthenticationFilter` but don't know how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303502/multiple-authentication-providers-in-spring-security

Probably you want to specify several providers. they will be checked in the same order.

Comment: How would I do that with the above java config? In one case I have saml2Login() and in the other a Filter.

Comment: You can define both configurations and give them order with @Order annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: I'm already using multiple @Order for different locations. Are you sure it can be used for the same location? I'd expect it to return a 403 as soon, as the first configuration denies the access?

Comment: Should be working did not try it myself but if you register 2 different providers they should chain and work in order. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers.

Comment: The "multiple entry points" link doesn't solve my issue: "The main motivation for having multiple entry points in one application is if there are different types of users that can access different portions of the application". I want to protect the same location with multiple authentication methods. I know the other link with the "multiple auth providers", but it is very special with the inMemoryAuthentication and the one customAuthProvider. Can you explain, how I would use that with saml2Login() and an AuthorizationFilter?

Comment: I see you got it finally ;) I hope I have been some help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The magic trick was the RequestHeaderRequestMatcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to

1. Duplicate the configuration with @Order and
2. Set a header based requestMatcher before the addFilter

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfiguration {
       @Order(100) // lower number = higher priority
       @Configuration
       @RequiredArgsConstructor
       public static class AppSecurityJWT extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
           final JWTUtil jwtUtil;

           @Override
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                   .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/saml2/service-provider-metadata/**", "/idm-app/**").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()

                   // This configuration will only be active if the Authorization header is present in the request
                   .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization")).addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil))
               ;
           }
       }

       @Order(101)
       @Configuration
       @RequiredArgsConstructor
       public static class AppSecuritySAML2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
           @Override
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               http
                   .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                   .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/saml2/service-provider-metadata/**", "/idm-app/**").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()

                   // This whole configuration will only be active, if the previous (100) didn't match
                   .saml2Login()
                   //...
           ;
       }
   }
   ```